# Can I use jQuery.ajax() inside an iframe hosted on a different server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, xss

I have a PHP project (I'm using CodeIgniter) with data capture. The form is hosted on mysite.com, and the iframe is on parentsite.com.

Is it possible to use jQuery / JavaScript validation within the iframe? I'm aware of the XSS issues about making requests to different domains, but does that mean different domain from the top URL or is it valid if it's the src of the iframe?

If this isn't possible, is there a way around it? The validation is checking whether somebody is unique, so some server-side validation has to take place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try it? What happened? Seems logical that you could have seen if it worked or fails on your own. :)

- If the iframe is calling the same domain that the iframe is loaded from there will be no problem.
- If the iframe is calling the parent domain, that is when you will run into the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

  - Work around for this one is to use [jsonp](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp)

Comment: The iframe src is mysite.com and the parent domain is parentsite.com. The AJAX call would be to mysite.com.

Comment: So that would be the first bullet since the call will be from example.com to example.com, not stackoverlfow.com to example.com.